# WAMP and XAMPP Show PHP Instead of Running It

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, wamp, wampserver

I understand that this is a problem with many others and that this question has been asked before, but no matter what, *nothing is working*.  In other situations, they get it eventually, but I've tried different versions of XAMPP and WAMP constantly and nothing works.  Here's some things that I *do* know:

- **The documents I'm trying to run are in the "www" folder (WAMP) and "htdocs" folder (XAMPP)**.  I'm using the default "test" pages that each program includes.  This also means that they're not using the short PHP tags and they are PHP file types.
- **With WAMP, the icon turns green**.  I've had a problem in the past where it stayed yellow/orange, but I got it to go green.  I also tried putting WAMP online, but that didn't make a difference.
- **Port 80 is not used**.  I changed Skype's settings to not use port 80.  I also changed Apache's listening port to 81 *temporarily*, but no change.
- ***Phpinfo()* and *localhost* work on WAMP and XAMPP**.
- **System Specs:** Windows 7 64-Bit.  (I've tried both 32-bit and 64-bit WAMP)
- **I tried it on my dad's laptop and that didn't work (Windows 7 32-bit)**.  So it must not be something wrong with *my* computer?
- **Typing *localhost/testmysql.php* in the address bar shows this:**
  [image: "mysql_connet()" warning message.]
  I'm not sure what that means, but since a default file is named "testmysql.php" in the "www" folder, this is odd.

If you have any questions, just leave a comment.  I'm sure that if this problem gets solved, then any situation that anyone else has can look here and find a solution.  Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: it means that your computer can't get the address for the first parameter in mysql_connect in your code...

Comment: I also put my own .PHP file in the folder that looks like this: `<?php echo "It works!"; ?>`.  And, well, it didn't...

Comment: Are you sure phpinfo() works? In which file phpinfo() statement works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I didn't think I'd be able to come up with a solution, but this "kinda" works.  Here's the thing:

I'm using *XAMPP* now, and I create a PHP file of my own (with `<?php echo "It works!"; ?>`) and put it in the "htdocs" folder.  When I double click on the file, it shows raw PHP code.  However, if I type "*localhost/test.php*", it works fine.

Now I'm not sure if the same thing works with WAMP because I uninstalled that before finding a solution.  I find it a bit frustrating that I have to type location of the file in the address bar to get it started, but once I do, the links to other pages work fine.

I hope you found this useful, guys.  If you have a solution to allow the PHP to run when double clicking on the file in the "htdocs" folder, go ahead, I don't mind changing correct answers :)

Comment: Using `localhost/test.php` was what was required to solve this on both WAMPServer and XAMPP. PHP is only compiled when Apache sees the `<?php` tag. So if you run the file by clicking on it from explorer, apache never gets to se the file

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visual-AMP, It is like the IIS, The right key can operate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to double click a php file to make it run.  The point of installing a server is to run the file on the server. PHP is server side and will never run correctly as a local file.  You must start with the web address "localhost" to run the file on the server.